# Wordpress menu z-index

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress menu is underneath the elements in the body of the page, when it shouldn't be.

I have checked the z-index over and over again.

The elements in the menu have a z-index of 99 and the elements in the body don't have a z-index value.  So in theory the menu should be over lap the elements in the body of the page, but it does.

So if it's not the z-index then that is it?

Note: I know people always want to have some code pasted in the question but the css is 1969 lines long and I don't know which part of that is wrong.  And I'm not going to paste 1969 lines into this question.

Comment: can you show some demo ?

Comment: Put the mouse over the "About" menu item and look at the drop down menu.  
http://www.kodemagd.de/about/eula/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay here is the solution 
 move to the file http://www.kodemagd.de/wp-content/themes/spun.2.0.2/spun/style.css?ver=3.9.1
go to 889 line and find

```
.hentry
```

just remove

```
position: relative
```

from this and then check the output